# Rails 3.2 with many stylesheet assets in dev mode => error with IE HTC-behaviours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am developing a new web application in Rails 3.2. I have come to the point where I am trying to make everything look as nice in IE as Firefox/Chrome etc.

For that I am using CSS3 PIE http://css3pie.com/

However: Because of the way stylesheets are fragmented out in many small files, I now have 64 stylesheet files to load in development mode. This creates a problem in IE, when css3pie.htc tries to dynamically create a new styleshhet. IE only supports 31 concurrent stylesheets.

Is there a way to make Rails always concatenate all stylesheets into application.css? In development.

**UPDATE 2012-04-11:** I have tried to invoke "rake assets:precompile" on my development machine. But the precompiled stylesheet is still not used. It seems like I need to change some config values, but I do not know which.

Carsten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your asset pipeline is in debug mode, so you'll want to turn that off.You should have a `<AppDir>/config/environments/development.rb` file. In that file, try to find the following line.

```
ServerPrototype::Application.configure do
    ...
    config.assets.debug = true
    ...
end
```

Try setting that value to `false` (if the line isn't in the file already, go ahead and add it with a value of `false`). That will cause the asset pipeline to compile all your assets into a **single file per manifest**

If that doesn't fix it, you may need to restructure your manifest files. I'd read through this section on the [Asset Pipeline: Manifests and Directives](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) to understand how the manifests are used and compiled.

You can also turn on compression if you want by adding/changing the following setting to true:

```
config.assets.compress = true
```

Note, that if you're using custom compressors, you'll also need to add those definitions as well:

```
config.assets.css_compressor = :foo_compressor
config.assets.css_compressor = :bar_compressor
```

A complete list of the config options for the asset pipeline can be found in the Rails [Guides Documentation on Configuring Rails Applications: Configuring Assests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets).

> `config.assets.compress` a flag that enables the compression of compiled assets. It is explicitly set to true in `config/production.rb`.
>
> `config.assets.debug` disables the concatenation and compression of assets. Set to false by default in `config/development.rb`.